# Simple exercise on t-Student test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I was trying to solve the following exercise:

"Given a population $\Omega$, normally distributed, and its sample $C=\left\{5,10,6,14\right\}$, calculate the confidence interval of the population mean with a $90\%$ significance level. Afterwards, test with a $1\%$ significance level if the population mean might be supposed equal to 10.$

First of all, I calculated the sample mean
$$\bar{X}=35/4,$$
then the unbiased sample variance
$$S^2=\frac{203}{16},$$
and finally I wrote the confidence interval
$$\left|\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}\right|<t_{0.90}(3)\Rightarrow-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{S}t_{0.90}+\bar{X}<\mu<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{S}t_{0.90}+\bar{X}.$$
Is that correct? I'm wondering if the "smallness" of the sample requires an altnernative procedure to solve the esercise.
Then I completed the latter calculating the statistics
$$T=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu_0}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}\simeq -0.68$$ 
and I stated the the null hypotesis should not be rejected since
$$|-0.68|<t_{0.975}(3)=3.182.$$
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're almost there. Just think what the "accepted region" will look like if you reject 10% on each side. This will create you an $80%$ confidence interval.

Comment: I think I've got what you meant. The quantile I should consider is $t_{0.95}$, isn't it? And what about the rest? Is everything ok?

Comment: You've got $\dfrac{\sqrt n} S$ where you need $\dfrac S {\sqrt n}. \qquad$

Comment: Yes, that's a typo! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The smallness of the sample is precisely the reason why it's important to use the t-distribution rather than the normal distribution, in this case with $3$ degrees of freedom.

$\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}
\text{wrong: } & \xcancel{-\frac{\sqrt n}S t_{0.95}+\bar{X}<\mu<\frac{\sqrt n}S t_{0.95}+\bar{X}. \vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}} } \\[10pt]
\text{right: } & -\frac S {\sqrt n} t_{0.95}+\bar{X}<\mu< \frac S {\sqrt n} t_{0.95}+\bar{X}.
\end{align}

Comment: May I ask you why $2$ degrees of freedom instead of $3$? The length of the sample is $4$.

Comment: @GianoRugge : Sorry -- typo. It's $3. \qquad$

Comment: @ MichaelHardy Moreover, the quantile should be $t_{0.95}$ since $5%$ is both in the right tail and in the left one, shouldn't it?

Comment: @GianoRugge : Correct. $\qquad$